# modify existing overlay

Tags: faces, overlays

How do I modify an existing overlay, more specifically, in spacemacs I have 
[image]

and the overlays are covering the all the parenthesis. Note that the overlays move depending on what inner set of parenthesis point is in. I would like to be able to tweaks the look of the overlays but I haven't seen any way of doing this. I tried modifying `rainbow-delimiters-depth-..` faces but as this is an overlay there is no change. The manual seems to require you to know the beginning and end of the overlay to change it. But since this is always changing, I do not see an easy way of doing that.

Comment: Put your cursor just before ("on") the highlighted text, then do `C-u C-x =`, and see what face is used for the overlay (near the bottom of `*Help*`). Then `M-x customize-face` for that face.

Comment: "*To customize various options, including the color theme*":  `M-x customize-group rainbow-delimiters` -- see the `README.md` of the repository:  https://github.com/Fanael/rainbow-delimiters ... "*You can specify custom colors by customizing following faces*":  Faces take the form `rainbow-delimiters-depth-N-face`, with `N` being the depth. Depth begins at 1, the outermost color. Faces exist for depths 1-9.  The unmatched delimiter face: `rainbow-delimiters-unmatched-face`.  The mismatched delimiter face: `rainbow-delimiters-mismatched-face`.

Comment: right so I am okay with using `C-u C-x =` but for my problem changing the color of `rainbow-delimiters` does not change the overlay. For whatever reason spacemacs uses an overlay ontop of `rainbow-delimiters-depth-1-face` which makes it look how it does in the screenshot.